# Failed to create the changeset: Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-sam

I am trying to deploy cloudformation stack into a cross-account account. However, when i am deploying the cloudfromation.yml file i am getting the following below error. I have even tried using cloudformation.yaml but same error.

However, when i try to create S3 bucket, the bucket is created without any problem. the issue only arises when doing lambda deployment

```
Waiting for changeset to be created..

Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: 
For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [helloworldpython3] is invalid. 'CodeUri' is not a valid S3 Uri of the form 's3://bucket/key' with optional versionId query parameter.
```

Here is my cloudformation.yml file that i have got, which is deploying a simple lambda function. I have even tried using cloudformation.yaml but i get the same error

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"
Description: A starter AWS Lambda function.

Resources:
  helloworldpython3:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: ./lambda
      Description: 'Lambda function for CD Demo'
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
```

Here is my buildspec.yml file that i have got setup

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo $CROSS_ACCOUNT_ROLE
      - echo $TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID
      - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      - chmod +x cross-account-setup.sh
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Start Deploy"
      - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      - . ./cross-account-setup.sh
      - >
        aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name amr-manual-deployment-cicd --template-file cloudformation-stack.yml --no-fail-on-empty-changeset 
      - echo "End Deploy"
```

What changes do i need to make in the .yml file in oder to deploy the cloud-formation stack successfully.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWS::Serverless::Function` syntax expects a s3 Uri. So `CodeUri` should be something like `'s3://testBucket/mySourceCode.zip'`.
In your codebuild, you have to add a step to zip and upload the source code to  s3 bucket before running the `cloudformation deploy` command. Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) for steps for packaging python applications.
If you want to avoid this overhead you can convert your application into a SAM and add [SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/install-sam-cli.html) in your codebuild environment to do the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Then you use transform you can say that you let CF "build" your lambda function and upload your artifact to a s3 bucket. Transform will rework your CF to point to these artifacts now stored in s3. And doing this in a cross-account solution can provide issues with read access for the CF to the artifacts.